# Max-height transition problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I make autocomplete
Max-height set from JavaScript:

```
if (data.length < 10) 
    element.css({'max-height': (30 * newVal.length) + 'px'})
```

If max-height decreases(e.g. 300px to 150px), transition does not work.

If max-height increases(e.g. 150px to 300px), transition works.

```
.autocomplete-ion {
 background-color: gray;
 position: absolute;
 width: 90%;
 left: 5%;
 top:45px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 z-index: 10000000;
 background-color: #FAFAFA;
 transition: 0.8s;
 max-height: 300px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.098),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.084);
 ul li {
   padding:5px;
 }
}
```

Comment: try this - element.css("max-height", " " + (30 * newVal.length) + "px");

Comment: Also you did not terminated the line with semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have max-height value as 300px in your css. So you should remove that to work properly

```
.autocomplete-ion {
 background-color: gray;
 position: absolute;
 width: 90%;
 left: 5%;
 top:45px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 z-index: 10000000;
 background-color: #FAFAFA;
 transition: 0.8s;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.098),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.084);
 ul li {
   padding:5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `height` change from `element` add/remove will not cause a animation.

When elements increasing, the new `height` is likely to always larger than previous `max-height`, so when you set a higher `max-height`, the animation appears from old `max-height` to new one.

When elements decreasing, if you remove the elements first, then the height will decrease first, without animation, then, when you set the new `max-height`, it'll only animate part only if new `max-height` is smaller than decreased height. And if the new `max-height` is still larger than decreased height, the animation not appears at all.

So you have to first set to the new `max-height` when new elements is less then old ones, to trigger animation, and set the list to new one(either by removing or create a new list) when animation ends.

```js
var list = $(".autocomplete-ion ul");

var tryAppend = function(newList) {
    var curList = $(".autocomplete-ion ul li");
    var curLength = curList.length;
    var newLength = newList.length;
    if (newLength <= 10) {
        // If its adding, no need to listen to animation, as the new height will be definetly larger.
        // Otherwise, 
        if (newLength < curLength) {
            $(".autocomplete-ion").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
                list.empty().append(newList);
                $(this).off();
            });
            $(".autocomplete-ion").css({'max-height': (30 * newLength) + 'px'});
        } else {
            $(".autocomplete-ion").css({'max-height': (30 * newLength) + 'px'});
            list.empty().append(newList);
        }  
    }   
};

var create = function(num) {
    var list =[];
    var i, li;
    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i ) {
        li = $("<li>").text("Test li " + (i + 1));
        list.push(li);
    }
    tryAppend(list);
};
$(".cl").click(function() {
    var counts = parseInt($(this).data("len"), 10);
    create(counts);
});
$(".clear").click(function() {
   list.empty();
});
```

```css
.autocomplete-ion {
     background-color: gray;
     position: absolute;
     width: 90%;
     left: 5%;
     top:45px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     z-index: 10000000;
     background-color: #FAFAFA;
     transition: 0.8s;
     max-height: 0px;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.098),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.084);
     ul li {
         height: 40px;
       padding:5px;
     }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="autocomplete-ion">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<button class="cl" data-len="1">1</button>
<button class="cl" data-len="5">5</button>
<button class="cl" data-len="10">10</button>
```